# Pipe a list or array in awk as variable (to be executed as parameter in other command)

Tags: bash, awk, pipe

I am trying to execute the one liner below as a part of bash script.

```
command1 |grep -ID|grep -v + | awk '{print "command2" $2}'|bash
```

The first part of the pipe prints the info below:

```
root@system:~# command1 |grep -v ID|grep -v +
| id                                   | name                     | mac_address       | fixed_ips                                                                            |
| 00277225-34fa-48f5-9a2a-ee5f1c5b1dcb | dummy                    | fa:18:3e:c4:85:94 | {"subnet_id": "0cd4d824-4420-4049-87c3-ed33c3addbf5", "ip_address": "11.170.1.121"}  |
:
:
| ff9a6ed5-9694-45bc-bf71-59565f96d809 | BAT-T0-A2-0-7-tport      | fa:18:3e:62:70:fb | {"subnet_id": "f9ae81ed-3b1a-45a7-96fd-c417ed32
```

So, $2 in awk command2 is "00277225-34fa-48f5-9a2a-ee5f1c5b1dcb".
e.g.

```
command2 00277225-34fa-48f5-9a2a-ee5f1c5b1dcb
```

The whole purpose of this one-liner is to execute a number of "command2" instances with different parameter values from the printout above.
e.g.

```
command2 00277225-34fa-48f5-9a2a-ee5f1c5b1dcb
command2 ff9a6ed5-9694-45bc-bf71-59565f96d809
:
:
```

But I can not make the $2 recognized the way below

```
command1 |grep -ID|grep -v + | awk '{print "command2" $2}'|bash
```

I think I am missing few syntax tricks here (as newbie).

p.s: If I copy / paste the whole line in command line, it works fine.

Comment: Can you please explain what the input is and what the expected output is more clearly?

Comment: And clarify if you are executing `command1 |grep -ID` or `command1 |grep -v ID` as you show both commands in your question and they are extremely different - one is passing the args `-I` and `-D` to grep while the other is deleting lines that contain the string `ID`.

Comment: my bad.! it should be "command1 |grep -v ID|grep -v +" .

Comment: OK, then edit your question to correct it, don't just stick a footnote in a comment and hope people trying to help you will notice it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for

```
command1 | awk '!/ID/ && !/\+/ {print $2}' | xargs -n 1 command2
```

I refactored the ugly [useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) `grep`s into the Awk script; but the real beef here is `xargs`.  It reads parameters from standard input and passes them on to the command you supply in the positional parameters.

The option `-n 1` says to only accept one additional argument at a time; but if `command2` is a well-written standard Unix command, it can probably accept an arbitrary number of arguments, and will simply loop over them.  In that case, removing `-n 1` will be a lot more efficient.

Incidentally, your original attempt was fairly close; you should have added a space after `command2` in the `print` statement.  But I hope this solution will also help you see how to "think Unix".

Comment: You don't need to escape the `+` as it's only an RE metacharacter when it appears after some RE segment that could be repeated, i.e. NOT at the start of an RE. Much more importantly though - with `command1 |grep -ID|...` the OP isn't grepping for the string "ID" in his question, he's calling `grep` with the args `-I` and `-D`. idk what those do s0 idk what the awk equivalent would be so maybe `command1 |grep -ID | awk '!/+/{print $2}'| xargs -n 1 command2` is good enough for what he wants. Having said that he also shows `command1 |grep -v ID|...` so idk what he's doing at all.

Comment: @EdMorton Good catch!  Luckily as per comments on the question itself it seems that the one I *didn't* miss was the intended action.